# How do I implement CircularProgressIndicator dialog and '"Message sent!" Dialog in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am a newbie in flutter and I would like to get assistance on how to implement CircularProgressIndicator dialog and "Message sent!" dialog when a flatbutton is pressed. In this case, I am implementing a contact form for users to send their messages through FirebaseFirestore.instance. My initial approach of setting a bool _isLoading and using it to trigger the CircularProgressIndicator is working only that it does not respond when I set it as false after the message has been sent. As a result, I am getting a CircularProgressIndicator that does not stop even after confirming that the message has been sent. Could anyone help me with this problem?

```
                            FlatButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isLoading = true;
                                });
                                if (_isLoading) {
                                  showDialog(
                                      barrierDismissible: true,
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return Dialog(
                                          child: Container(
                                            height: _height * 0.09495,
                                            width: _width * 0.17644444,
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 15,
                                            ),
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                  Text('Please wait...'),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      });
                                  if (_fbKey.currentState.saveAndValidate()) {
                                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                        .collection('message')
                                        .doc()
                                        .set({
                                      'name': _fbKey.currentState.value['name'],
                                      'email':
                                          _fbKey.currentState.value['email'],
                                      'details':
                                          _fbKey.currentState.value['details'],
                                      'category':
                                          _fbKey.currentState.value['category'],
                                      'created': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                                    }).then((_) {
                                      print('Sent!');
                                    }).catchError((error) {
                                      print("Failed to send message: $error");
                                    });
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  showDialog(
                                      barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                                      barrierDismissible: true,
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return Dialog(
                                          child: Container(
                                            height: _height * 0.09495,
                                            width: _width * 0.17644444,
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Message sent2!',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.green,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      });
                                }
                                setState(() {
                                  _isLoading = false;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
'''
```

Comment: Why not set the state of _isLoading after then?

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested but I am still getting a continuous CircularProgressIndicator. Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: Why not try debugging line by line and check if it is going to the line where the value of isLoading is changing or not.
If not debugging then lazy method would be putting print like print('i am here);  above the isLoading = false;

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Here to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need booleans to show and pop dialogs. This logic can easily be implemented if we understand **asynchronous** functions and **await** calls. As soon as the form is validated we will show loading dialog and then await firebase query. When firebase query is executed we will see if it has caught error or successfully executed using try catch block. If it has caught an error we will pop the dialog, print error and then call return so our method is terminated. If it hasn't caught any error it will continue normal executed.We will pop this dialog and show message sent dialog.

```
FlatButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          onPressed: () async {
    
            if (_fbKey.currentState.saveAndValidate()) {
              showDialog(
                  barrierDismissible: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Dialog(
                      child: Container(
                        height: _height * 0.09495,
                        width: _width * 0.17644444,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 15,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              Text('Please wait...'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
    
              try{
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('message')
                    .doc()
                    .set({
                  'name': _fbKey.currentState.value['name'],
                  'email':
                  _fbKey.currentState.value['email'],
                  'details':
                  _fbKey.currentState.value['details'],
                  'category':
                  _fbKey.currentState.value['category'],
                  'created': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                });
              } catch (e){
                //Pop loading dialog because error has occured. We will print error and call return so our function
                //should be terminated 
                Navigator.pop(context);
                print("Exception occured");
                return;
              }
              
              //Pop loading dialog because query is executed and now we want to show message sent dialog
              Navigator.pop(context);
    
              print("Query successfully executed i.e Message Sent");
    
              showDialog(
                  barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                  barrierDismissible: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Dialog(
                      child: Container(
                        height: _height * 0.09495,
                        width: _width * 0.17644444,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Message sent2!',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It actually works. I didn't know that booleans were unnecessary for this case. I will focus on learning asynchronous functions and await calls for now. Once again thank you!